# How to get the same appearance for an editable and non-editable Android Textview?

Tags: android, android-layout, textview

I have 2 Textviews, one is editable and the other is not, but they look different : the editable textview has a larger fontsize than the non-editable.
I understand that the fontcolor of the non-editable is grey and the editable one is black. But i don't like that the font size is different.

How can I make sure that the font size is exactly the same ?

I am using the following theme in the manifest file : android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"

```
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/etPutNameID"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:background="@null"
        android:ellipsize="middle"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:hint="@string/textViewPutName"
        android:maxLength="75"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:textColor="#000000" />


   <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvTakeSelfieID"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:background="@null"
        android:editable="false"
        android:ellipsize="middle"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:hint="@string/textViewTakeSelfie"
        android:maxLength="75"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:textColor="#000000" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just style it this way:

```
 <EditText
        android:id="@+id/etPutNameID"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:background="@null"
        android:ellipsize="middle"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:hint="@string/textViewPutName"
        android:maxLength="75"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:textSize="10sp"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:textColor="#000000" />


   <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvTakeSelfieID"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:background="@null"
        android:editable="false"
        android:ellipsize="middle"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:hint="@string/textViewTakeSelfie"
        android:maxLength="75"
        android:textSize="10sp"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:textColor="#000000" />
```

OR put this into style.xml

```
<style name="UnifiedText">
    <item name="android:textSize">10sp</item>
    <item name="android:background">@android:color/transparent</item>
</style>
```

and put this attribute into both widgets:

```
style="@style/UnifiedText"
```